# How to join three sql tables in one query

Tags: sql

I have tw tables with rows user_id and I want to select all the users which appears in these two tables. That is, I want to select distinct userid from both tables and then find the corresponding users. How can I achieve this?

User (id, email) {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

table1(user_id) {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1}

table2(user_id) {1, 3, 4, 10, 10, 10, 10}

dsitinct from table1 {1, 2}

distinct from table2 {1, 3, 4, 10}

after the join with user {1, 2, 3, 4, 10} with the respective email too

Comment: Can you please share your tables' structure, some sample data and the result you want?

Comment: Are you aware of `INNER JOIN`s?

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: [example](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/11/how-to-join-three-tables-in-sql-query-mysql-sqlserver.html)

refer this link.. and more important.. google first before asking in stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

SELECT USER_ID
FROM TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.USER_ID = TABLE2.USER_ID

That will return all of the user ids present in BOTH tables.  If you have duplicate IDs for some reason you can use a SELECT DISTINCT USER_ID
for the first line

If you want the all User IDs that appear in either table (giving you all in either table so they don't have to be in both) change the INNER join to an OUTER join.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a couple of `IN` operators:

```
SELECT id, email
FROM   users
WHERE  id IN (SELECT user_id FROM table1) OR
       id IN (SELECT user_id FROM table2)
```